# Android Sqlite query returning Empty set when there is Data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, android-database

I am having a **Database Adapter** that extends ***SQLiteOpenHelper***.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public SQLiteDatabase database;
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    database = this.getWritableDatabase();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Creating Image table
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+IMAGE_TABLE+"("
            +IMAGE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            +IMAGE_DATA+" BLOB NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+CREDIT_CATEGORY_TABLE+"("
            +CREDIT_CATEGORY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            +CREDIT_CATEGORY_NAME+" VARCHAR(256) UNIQUE NOT NULL,"
            +CREDIT_CATEGORY_IMAGE+" INTEGER DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES "+IMAGE_TABLE+"("+IMAGE_ID+") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE);");
}
}
```

This is the **Database Structure** that is relevent to this question. And with such Structure, I am *querying a row* for populating the RecyclerView Adapter as shown below....

```
Cursor c = database.query(CREDIT_CATEGORY_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null,position+",1");
```

With the **CREDIT_CATEGORY_ID** returned from this query, I am allowing the data to be **deleted** in the application through a ***method***(this method is within DatabaseAdapter).

```
public boolean deleteCreditCategory(int creditCategoryId) {
    if(isCreditCategoryDeletable(creditCategoryId)) {
        // TODO DEBUG this: The query function is always returning an Empty set
        Cursor c = database.query(CREDIT_CATEGORY_TABLE,new String[] {CREDIT_CATEGORY_IMAGE,CREDIT_CATEGORY_ID},CREDIT_CATEGORY_ID+"=?",new String[] {creditCategoryId+""},null,null,null);
        database.beginTransaction();
        if( database.delete(CREDIT_CATEGORY_TABLE,CREDIT_CATEGORY_ID+" = ?",new String[] {creditCategoryId+""}) == 1 )
        {
            // TODO BUG_INFO: since the query method returning empty set, we can't moveToFirst()...
            if(!c.moveToFirst()) {
                database.endTransaction();
                return false;
            }
            if(c.isNull(c.getColumnIndex(CREDIT_CATEGORY_IMAGE))) {
                database.setTransactionSuccessful();
                database.endTransaction();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                int imageId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CREDIT_CATEGORY_IMAGE));
                if( this.deleteImage(imageId) ) {
                    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    database.endTransaction();
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    database.endTransaction();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            database.endTransaction();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Since this query `c.query()` is **always returning an Empty set**, The  method `c.moveToFirst()` is returning *false* and the DeleteCreditCategory method is returning false indicating a Failure.

I am pretty **sure of the results is Empty** as I checked that through ***Debug*** and `Log.d()`.There is sure data available in the Database.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: what `creditCategoryId` are you passing to that method? where do you get it from?

Comment: I am passing the ID value I got from the `Cursor c = database.query(CREDIT_CATEGORY_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null,position+",1");` to the `deleteCreditCategory()` method

Comment: what does `position` have to do with database row id?

Comment: To be more precise, I am filling an RecyclerViewAdapter. The adapter will pass the position of the Element It needs, So the Selection is Based on Position. The Returned row contains the ID,Name & Image_id (foreign key); This ID is passed to the method `deleteCreditCategory()`

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter as a base class - it has `getItemId()` method implemented which returns correct row id

Comment: @pskink ,the creditCategoryId returned from my Adapter is correct. I think the problem is as stated by @MikeT in the below Answer. 

I will try out his Solution tonight. I think the problem might be, the **cursor** is **Evaluated** only while calling `getCount()` or `moveToFirst()`; that in my case that row is deleted before ***evaluating*** the Cursor. 

Thanks for the help too.... Also suggest me If I am wrong in any case.

Comment: what actually do you want to do inside `deleteCreditCategory` method? dont you think that what you do is overcomplicated?

Comment: @pskink, I want to delete the row having the ID of *creditCategoryId*. Sometimes, these Table also has Foreign Key (**CREDIT_CATEGORY_IMAGE**). I wanted the **Image Entry** (on the Image_table) pointed by this row to be ***deleted as well*** along with this row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue may be that you delete the row and this is then reflected in the cursor which you then look at and hence is empty, as beleive that a cursor is only actually obtained when you move within it (which includes using the `getCount` method, so `getCount` could be used instead of `moveToFirst`).

I suggest you try to get the row information before the delete and then delete after getting the information from the row.

No use checking for null cursor, it will not be null if the query works.

So perhaps you want something like :-

```
public boolean deleteCreditCategory(int creditCategoryId) {
    if(isCreditCategoryDeletable(creditCategoryId)) {
        // TODO DEBUG this: The query function is always returning an Empty set
        Cursor c = database.query(CREDIT_CATEGORY_TABLE,new String[] {CREDIT_CATEGORY_IMAGE,CREDIT_CATEGORY_ID},CREDIT_CATEGORY_ID+"=?",new String[] {creditCategoryId+""},null,null,null);
        if (Cursor.moveTofirst) {
            int imageid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CREDIT_CATEGORY_IMAGE));
            database.beginTransaction();
            if (database.delete(CREDIT_CATEGORY_TABLE,CREDIT_CATEGORY_ID+" = ?",new String[] {creditCategoryId+""}) == 1) {
                if( this.deleteImage(imageId) ) {
                    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    database.endTransaction();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            database.endTransaction();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

*Note! I haven't tested this so there may be the odd typo or error.*

Comment: You are Right Buddy, the Cursor is fetching the ResultSet into Itself only when we asks for data from It like `getCount()`,`moveToFirst()`,`getInt()`, etc......